# Jinja2 template is not detecting my python variable

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to use a simple if statement in a jinja2 template as such:

testing.html :

```
{% if typeEntry %}
   *insert code A here*       
{% else %}
   *insert code B here*
{% endif %}
```

testing.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def testing():
    typeEntry = "new"
    return render_template("testing.html")
```

Even though typeEntry variable is defined in my python code, code A is never shown only code B, I have no idea why.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre].

Comment: @MattDMo i edited it, is it better now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass all the variables you want to inject in the template in the `render_template` function call, in your case:

```
@app.route('/')
def testing():
    typeEntry = "new"
    return render_template("testing.html", typeEntry=typeEntry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable to `render_template()`:

```
return render_template("testing.html", typeEntry=typeEntry)
```